# README.md showing as index file in github page [hugo blog engine deployment]

Tags: github-pages, hugo, readme

*Heading a issue while rendering posts as static pages hosted in github ...
What I am willing to complete is a personal blog environment with Hugo!
By so far I have run the site locally and went well...but while deploying in Github the only thing I get when I visit the site is

> Blockquote

README.md rendered as index page on :https://passager07.github.io/
I am not making it to access the **...content/post/[post].md**

> Blockquote

https://github.com/passager07/passager07.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution of this problem was found by :

1. Constructing my new repository without Readme.md file and licence.
2. Playing around on localhost with hugo and all the configuration (including theme) to get the greatest satisfaction!
3. Making sure that  **public** folder is created running hugo
4. Getting a .gitingore file on **public** folder
5. Pushing it to my repository on master branch

After this steps I let https://www.netlify.com do the rest by automatic deployment!

Answer (score 1):

**[Hugo](https://gohugo.io/)** is for generating a static html pages: that measn you need your GutHub page space to points to those generated html pages, not md files.

You can generate those html pages in a `docs` folder ([since August 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1428830/6309)) or in a `gh-pages` branch.

See more at "[Hugo: Hosting on GitHub Pages](https://gohugo.io/tutorials/github-pages-blog/)", which uses for instance a `config.toml` with:

```
publishDir: "docs"
```

> After running `hugo`, push your `master` branch to the remote repo and choose the docs folder as the website source of your repo.

Comment: Sorry for being kind of confused but what the folder "docs" should contain..?

Comment: @TahirllariAldo the html generated files for your website. See https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing, and https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/

Comment: After reading carefully all the documentations provided for this topic... I concluded that the only way to generated files to work was putting them in a 'gh-pages' branch and then :

Comment: . For some reason (the way I set up all the things) github didn't provide such configuration as choosing **docs folder as the website source of the repo**. So I found another **solution** that I am posting below! Anyway I appreciate your valuable respond @VonC !